# Can an orchid be revived with no roots?

Tags: orchids

Unfortunately someone decided to water one of my phalenopsis while I was away. I came back to a smelly mess with all the leaves dead, two stems still present and green from when it flowered 6 months ago, and all the roots that were in the bark rotted. I don't see any viable roots.

I'm wondering if it's even possible to save it.

For the moment I've put what was the roots under continuous running water ( aquarium waterfall ) to see if I can supply it highly oxygenated water.  I'm going away again so I can not rely on anyone just watering out daily.

Anyone think this might work? Our should I try something else?

[image]

Comment: If you manage to revive this plant, it'll be close to a miracle... Sorry.

Comment: https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/flowers/orchids/growing-orchids-in-water.htm

Answer (score 3):

Being a Phalaenopsis, with my limited knowledge of them I imagine it will hate your treatment to constant moisture (oxygenated or not, and that appears to be the reason for your dilema) they dislike frequent watering. 
My only suggestion would be to put the remaining bulb part back (as it looks to have some semblance of root there) to suitably aerated orchid/bark pot mix, give it an ice cube once a week to drink and hope for the best. 
I tend to agree with Stephie, but miracles do happen!

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the best way to save this plant is to propagate by cuttings. The stems, if still viable, can be cut in smaller parts (the nodes are very important). You want them then to grow new roots.

Here is a simple [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3txXuEQLyQw) of how it's done on youtube. You'll need some charcoal if I understood correctly. I have no hands on experience with *Phalaenopsis* propagation, so I don't know how difficult it would be. But I think it is the best option left in your situation.